# substring formation

Tags: formatting, substring, sql-server-2014

ex) Recalc 20156593415896532
ex) Recalc of 2015658926358915 revised
ex) Recalc to clm 20156496874153157815 error

Here are few examples. I need to pull only the invoice numbers from the notes. The number is either 16 or 20 characters long.

I tried select substring(note,7,16)
but that would only work for first note and would pull wrong results for 2nd and 3rd note.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: sql server 2014 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you could do something like this:

```
select t3.number
from t outer apply
     (select stuff(t.notes, 1, patindex(' [0-9]', t.notes) + 1, '') as notes1
     ) t2 outer apply
     (select left(t2.notes1, charindex(' ', t2.notex1)) as number
     ) t3;
```